# ScrollTop not being correctly calculated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been pulling my hair out on this one for a while and would appreciate your help. When you try to go to the following link, the details of the physician display and scroll correctly: https://artesiageneral.com/our-staff/#gallery-details-william-j-baggs-md

However, when you go to the link on the same page of one of the Advanced Practitioners, ex. https://artesiageneral.com/our-staff/#gallery-details-ron-haugen-dnp , it opens the details element, but does not scroll to it correctly.

The markup to both sections are the same as far as I can tell.

I went through the applicable code. I think the galleryItemDetailsOffset is being calculated incorrectly (about 12000px), but I don't know why this is. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
else if(location.hash.substr(1,15)=="gallery-details")
    {
        var detailsBlock = $('[id="' + location.hash.substr(1) + '"]');
        $(".gallery_item_details_list .gallery_item_details").css("display", "none");
        detailsBlock.css("display", "block");
        var galleryItem = $('[id="gallery-item-' + location.hash.substr(17) + '"]');
        detailsBlock.find(".prev").attr("href", (galleryItem.prevAll(":not('.isotope-hidden')").first().length ? galleryItem.prevAll(":not('.isotope-hidden')").first().find(".open_details").attr("href") : $(".mc_gallery").children(":not('.isotope-hidden')").last().find(".open_details").attr("href")));
        detailsBlock.find(".next").attr("href", (galleryItem.nextAll(":not('.isotope-hidden')").first().length ? galleryItem.nextAll(":not('.isotope-hidden')").first().find(".open_details").attr("href") : $(".mc_gallery").children(":not('.isotope-hidden')").first().find(".open_details").attr("href")));
        var visible=parseInt($(".gallery_item_details_list").height())==0 ? false : true;
        var galleryItemDetailsOffset;
        var parentDetailsList = $(detailsBlock).closest(".gallery_item_details_list");

        if(!visible)
        {
            parentDetailsList.css("display", "block").animate({height:detailsBlock.height()}, 500, 'easeOutQuint', function(){
                $(this).css("height", "100%");
                $(window).trigger("resize");
            });
            galleryItemDetailsOffset = parentDetailsList.offset();
            if(typeof(galleryItemDetailsOffset)!="undefined")
                $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: galleryItemDetailsOffset.top-10}, 400);
        }
```

Comment: That's because at the time the hash gets parsed, the images still have not loaded. When they will, they'll push your target below and make it seems the calculation was incorrect. But it was actually correct at the time it's been made. So to workaround this, wait for your page to have fully loaded before executiong this script.